# Cross-fade div on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, fade

I want my background image to change when the mouse hovers over each menu item. My code works but, when the images `fadeout` and `fadein`, there is a white flash in between. To remove it, I want the images to cross-fade instead of just fading out and in.

How I can achieve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".home-menu-list li a").mouseenter(function() {
     var bannerClass = '#home-banner-' + $(this).attr('id');
     $('.active-banner').not(bannerClass).stop().fadeOut().removeClass('active-banner');
     $(bannerClass).stop().fadeIn().addClass('active-banner');
   });
 });
```

```css
.main-banner-wrapper img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid ">
  <div id="home-banner-1" class="active-banner">
    <div class="main-banner-wrapper">
      <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5145/5576437826_940f2db110.jpg" alt="Image 1" class="upload">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6  visible-lg visible-md visible-sm  front-text">
      <p>Thethe world.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="home-banner-2" style="display:none">
    <div class="main-banner-wrapper">
      <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3611/3463265789_586ce40aef.jpg" class="upload">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6  visible-lg visible-md visible-sm  front-text">
      <p>Thethe world.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="home-banner-3" style="display:none">
    <div class="main-banner-wrapper">
      <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5263/5601183065_f88a48d599.jpg" class="upload">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6  visible-lg visible-md visible-sm  front-text">
      <p>The around the world.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--content-->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="main-logo-panel">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 main-logo"></div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-8 main-menu">
          <ul class="list-inline home-menu-list">
            <li><a href="#" id="1">Rigging</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" id="2">Hatches </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" id="3">Stoppers</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

View on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/te69783s/)

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle, or at least the CSS as well. It sounds like something that could simply be done in CSS

Comment: @kthornbloom fiddle added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve almost the same using CSS.

Some small CSS changes:

add `transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;` to the `.main-banner-wrapper img`

and  add the following CSS:

```
.container-fluid .active-banner img {
    opacity:1; }

.container-fluid img {
    opacity:0; }
```

and remove the `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()`from the jQuery

see the example on 
http://jsfiddle.net/m92aotbd/2/

Answer (score 3):

Ah, you were almost there. You just needed position absolute to prevent the first one from bumping the next down down during the crossfade.

http://jsfiddle.net/te69783s/1/

```
.main-banner-wrapper img {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.container-fluid {
    height:500px;
}
```